# How can I connect to the server?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I've just started taking network programming classes and this is what we did in class in order to make connection between client and server. My problem is that I cannot connect to the server, it just stops after printing "addrinfo is successful" and does not loop through.

We used 8080 for port number in class and that did not work, so I tried using 7070 and it worked maybe 1 out of 50 times. I don't have any problems with the client side of the program, it works completely fine. I'm using Visual Studio Code on MacBook if that makes any difference, I also tried using the terminal but that did not work either.

//client to server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
const char *hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const char *portNumber = "7070";

int clientSocket; //socketFD
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
struct addrinfo *results; // const for head
struct addrinfo *record; // temp for traversing
int error;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

error = getaddrinfo(hostname, portNumber, &hints, &results);
// error checking
if(error >= 0){
printf("Client: getaddressinfo() successful\n ");
}
//traversing the list
for(record = results; record != NULL; record = record->ai_next){
    clientSocket = socket(record->ai_family, record->ai_socktype, 0);
    if(clientSocket == -1){
        continue;
        }
    if(connect(clientSocket, record->ai_addr, record-> ai_addrlen) != -1){
        break;
    } 
    close(clientSocket);  
}
//socket() and connect() both were success
//send()
if(record == NULL){
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
freeaddrinfo(results);
printf("socket status: created and connected\n");
char *message = "Hello" ; 

if(send(clientSocket, message, strlen(message), 0) == -1){
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else{
    printf("Message sent successfuly\n");
    }
close(clientSocket);
return 0;    

}
```

//server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

printf("Starting the server\n");
const size_t bufferSize = 1024;
const char *portNumber = "7070";
const int backlog = 1;
int serverSocket;
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
struct addrinfo *results;
struct addrinfo *record;

if((getaddrinfo(NULL, portNumber, &hints, &results)) != 0){
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("addrinfo is successful\n");

//traverse through the list
for(record = results; record != NULL; record = record->ai_next){
    serverSocket = socket(record->ai_family, record->ai_socktype, record->ai_protocol);

    if(serverSocket == -1){
        continue;
    }
    int enable = 1;
    setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int));

    if(bind(serverSocket, record->ai_addr, record->ai_addrlen) == 0){
        break;
    }
    close(serverSocket);

}
if(record == NULL){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
freeaddrinfo(results);
printf("Socket status: created and binded successfuly\n");
if(listen(serverSocket, backlog) == -1){
    printf("ERROR\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Server is listening\n");
while(1){
    int clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr clientAddress;
    socklen_t clientAddressLength = sizeof(clientAddress);
    if((clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, &clientAddress, &clientAddressLength)) <0){
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    } 
    printf("Client socket accepted\n");
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    if(recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1){
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Message is received: %s\n", buffer);
    close(clientSocket);
    printf("Client socket is closed\n");

}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: On your server, you appear to be missing `hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;` in the hint setup for `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: `getaddrinfo` may be failing. Your error checking is wrong so you won't be able to tell. `getaddrinfo` returns 0 on success and non-zero otherwise. So `if(error >= 0)` should be `if(error == 0)`